# Customization with a custom web service endpoint not refreshing

Tags: acumatica

I extended the StockItem with a few user fields, then created a custom web service end point to extend the StockItem with my changes. That worked great until I added another field. The customization package contains the changes (I verified in the XML) but when deployed to my production system its ignored. The old web service remains.

Has anyone else experienced this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean "deployed to my production system" ? So you have a separate development system ? when you created the custom endpoint, did you create/updated it on both ?

Comment: 2 separate systems for staging. I updated the endpoint in the dev system, exported the customization package (zip), then imported the zip into the production system and published. Turns out, the publish feature "execute all database scripts" was needed to force the package to reload the revised end points.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the publish feature "execute all database scripts" was needed to force the package to reload the revised endpoints.